# How to get children data from json via linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm using json.net and i've a json data like that,

```
[
{
  "ID":1098,
  "Name":"JC",
  "Issues":[
     {
        "PriorityLevel":"Low",
        "State":"Open"
     },
     {
        "PriorityLevel":"Low",
        "State":"Open"
     }
  ]
}
]
```

I just want to get childeren data from Issues via linq. I can reach parent but cannot children. If i reach children data directly i don't need to put more than one for loop.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Bora You have asked 7 questions on this site before. Each of these questions you are allowed to "Accept" an answer as THE answer to your question. You have not done this for any of your questions. Go to the past questions and hit the green checkmark below the answer that helped you solve your question.

Comment: Okey, I'll do it sorry again. Thank you

Comment: To be fair, only one of his other questions was answered at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a Json Object and extract the properties into an Anonymouse type that you can then query with Linq.

```
string response = @"[{
  ""ID"":1098,
  ""Name"":""JC"",
  ""Issues"":[
     {
        ""PriorityLevel"":""Low"",
        ""State"":""Open""
     },
     {
        ""PriorityLevel"":""Low"",
        ""State"":""Open""
     }
  ]}]";

var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response);
var issues = jsonObject["Issues"].Select(x => new
             {
                 PriorityLevel = (string)x.SelectToken("PriorityLevel"),
                 State = (string)x.SelectToken("State")
             });
```

You use SelectToken to grab the children of Issues. Now you can query issues for whatever you want.

```
var lowPriorities = issues.Where(x => x.PriorityLevel == "Low");
```

Here is a direct link to the json.net page on "[Deserializing Using LINQ Example](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm)".

Comment: I get this error.

Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: The reason is that the code has used JObject, rather than JArray

Comment: @Bora I added a link to Json.Nets web page, see if the documentation can help you get it working on your end.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
{
    var json = @"[      {
    ""ID"":1098,
    ""Name"":""JC"",
    ""Issues"":[
        {
            ""PriorityLevel"":""Low"",
            ""State"":""Open""
        },
        {
            ""PriorityLevel"":""Low"",
            ""State"":""Open""
        }
    ]}]";

    var a = JArray.Parse(json);

    var issues = a.SelectMany (x => x["Issues"]);
    var lowPriorities = issues.Where(x => ((string) x["PriorityLevel"]) == "Low");
}
```